# Can I use Npgsql as ad-hoc query tool with VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npgsql

I can use npgsql to create a PostgreSQL Data Connection in Visual Studio and run very simple SQL, using the Query Designer tool.

However, what I'd been hoping for was functionality to edit ad-hoc SQL, select blocks, comment other blocks out, and execute the selected SQL. That is, work with messy little windows like:

```
select * from customer.subscriptions;
select * from customer.customers;

/*insert into customer.customers ... 
etc etc---
*/
```

in a similar way to how I can work within Visual Studio's T-SQL Editor against SQL Server, or in other ad-hoc tools like pgAdmin or HeidiSQL.

But the Query Designer tool insists on only working with a query pane that it can completely map to its SQL pane, and returns errors if it can't map the entire SQL Pane to the Show Diagram Pane.

Can I do what I'm trying to do from within Visual Studio?  For example, can I either get turn off the extra cleverness in Query Designer or trick the T-SQL editor into playing with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm not sure Visual Studio's SQL/query support was meant to be as powerful as T-SQL or pgadmin. I worked on Npgsql's Visual Studio integration, I'd be happy to add any features missing at the Npgsql. I'd suggesting playing around with what VS can do with SqlServer (you can use a simple local file), and opening issue for anything you can do with SqlServer that you can't do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks Shay.  I don't fully understand the integration points.  Does the Npgsql code fully control the Query Designer GUI?  Or is that MSFT code with you implementing interfaces?  The functionality I'm looking for is conceptually very simple -- run the selected (semicolon delimited if possible) SQL code without trying to do anything with the SQL Designer pane.  But I don't know if you have enough control over the GUI to do something like that.

Comment: Most of what you is Microsoft functionality, Npgsql in theory simply provides only the specifics for PostgreSQL. But like I said, SqlServer should provide the maximum that VS provides built-in. If there's something you see there that Npgsql doesn't provide, then that can probably be added easily. Otherwise that's totally new, customized functionality.

Comment: OK, makes sense. MSFT's T-SQL editor (part of VS2015 as the default editor for *.sql) is a totally different GUI from what you get to work with through Data Connections, and assuming you're limited to Data Connections it doesn't sound like they're giving you the hook points you would need here.

Comment: Right, it would make sense for T-SQL to be a completely separate product tied to SqlServer (much like PostgreSQL's pgadmin). However, it's definitely worth exploring the limits of what VS can provide by seeing what's possible with its SqlServer support - it's entirely possible that some available GUI components have simply not been "turned on" by Npgsql.